# iterate declared arraylists in java

Tags: java, reflection, loops

I have a similar problem that is described below:

[iterate static int values in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271109/iterate-static-int-values-in-java)

The difference is that in my class I have elements that are ArrayLists (all ArrayLists contains elements of the same type), not primitive types.

I would like to know whether it is possible to iterate elements and inside this loop iterate declared ArrayList?

Comment: Can you give an example? Your question is a little vague. What do the ArrayLists contain ? Other reference types?

Comment: Yes, it is another reference type.

Comment: So you clarify: You have an `ArrayList` of some reference type `A` and you want to iterate over your `ArrayList` so you can access each of these `A` objects ?

Comment: I am sure the solution to original problem would be easier compared to problem itself. So key here is to understand what he wants :)

Comment: Yes, exactly. Similarly like in the link in the post, but instead of ints I have ArrayLists. And I would like to iterate over them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly iterate over `ArrayList`s, so your example is different from the link you posted, they needed to use reflection to iterate them because they weren't already grouped into a container:

```
class MyClass {
   public static ArrayList<A> myList = new ArrayList<>(
                                       Arrays.asList(new A[]{ A1, A2, ..., AN);

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       // iterate over your list
       for(A a : myList) {
          // do something with A object
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Indeed it looks like a sufficient solution. Anyway, now I will try to code this. Once again thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to iterate over an `ArrayList<Type>` of a refrence type
I found the following ways useful, you could try out yourself.

A. The most common/simple way of doing it, by using a counter
   to list its elements

> ```
>     ArrayList<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();
>     //Add some person objects to the list
>     for(int i=0;i<persons.size();i++){    
>     System.out.println(persons.get(i));
>     }
> ```

B. Using an iterator

> ```
>    for (Iterator i = persons.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
>      Object listElement = i.next();
>      System.out.println(listElement);
>    }
> ```

C. A For/in loop

> ```
>   for (Person listElement : persons) {
>      System.out.println(listElement); 
>    }
> ```

You could possibly use any of the 3 methods to get your work done,
but it is recommended to use the last method which is the For/in loop
since you won't have to use a counter (usually called `i` or `count`) or a `Iterator`